# Still not clear yet why all the ships are not moving to the direction they are facing after rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void MoveShips()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < spheres [0].transform.childCount; index++) {
            Transform oneChild = spheres [0].transform.GetChild (index);
            lastPositions [index] = oneChild.transform.position;
            if (!hasRotated [index]) 
            {
                oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            } 
            else 
            {
                oneChild.transform.position += oneChild.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            }
        }

        if (updateOn == true) {
            for(int index =0;index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
            {
                Transform child = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);

                distanceTraveled[index] += Vector3.Distance (child.transform.position, lastPositions [index]);
                if (distanceTraveled [index] >= randomNumbers [index] && !hasRotated [index]) 
                {
                    targetAngles = child.transform.eulerAngles + 180f * Vector3.up;
                    StartCoroutine (TurnShip (child.transform, child.transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, smooth));
                    hasRotated [index] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator TurnShip(Transform ship, Vector3 startAngle, Vector3 endAngle, float smooth)
    {
        float lerpSpeed = 0;

        while(lerpSpeed < 1)
        {
            ship.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, lerpSpeed);
            lerpSpeed += Time.deltaTime * smooth;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

For example i have 300 ships. They are moving forward using Vector3.forward then i want to make that after each child completed the rotation then change it's moving direction to the direction it's facing now. So in the case i rotate the ships 180 degrees but the ships move up.

This line make them move up:

```
oneChild.transform.position += oneChild.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
```

I tried also to change this line to:

```
oneChild.transform.position += oneChild.transform.forward * moveSpeed;
```

This make the ships to disapear.

I also tried:

```
oneChild.transform.position += oneChild.transform.forward * -1 * moveSpeed;
```

Or

```
oneChild.transform.position += -oneChild.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed; --- This line make the ships move up turn and move down. But i want them to move forward not up and down. Move forward to the direction they are facing after the rotation.
```

Or

```
oneChild.transform.position += oneChild.transform.forward * -1;
```

I also tried to use only the Vector3 for example:

```
if (!hasRotated [index]) 
            {
                oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            } 
            else 
            {
                oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            }
```

But this will move the ships back not to the direction they are facing. If i will rotate the ships only 60 degrees they will move back not to the facing direction.

Another problem i think it's a problem the ships change the moving diection if it's up down before they completed the rotation. I want that first the ship each ship will complete the rotation and while rotating to keep moving to the original direction only when the rotation end then change the movement to the direction it's facing.

The script

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class SphereBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject SpaceShip;
    GameObject[] spheres;
    public float moveSpeed = 50;

    private float distanceTravelled;
    public bool updateOn = true;
    private Vector3 lastPosition;

    List<bool> hasRotated = new List<bool>();
    List<float> distanceTraveled = new List<float>();
    List<Vector3> lastPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    List<int> randomNumbers = new List<int> ();

    public float smooth = 1f;
    private Vector3 targetAngles;
    private bool isRunning = false;

    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _sphereCount;
    private float _sphereSize;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int SphereCount;
    public float SphereSize;

    private void rndNumbers()
    {
        int Min = 20;
        int Max = 50;
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random ();
        randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(Min, Max).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(spheres[0].transform.childCount).ToList();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        UpdateSpheres ();
        spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MySphere");
        rndNumbers ();
        for(int index = 0; index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
        {
            Transform child = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);
            lastPosition = new Vector3(child.transform.position.x,child.transform.position.y,child.transform.position.z);
            lastPositions.Add (lastPosition);
            hasRotated.Add(false);
            distanceTraveled.Add(0f);
        }
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        SphereCount = Mathf.Max(0, SphereCount);
        SphereSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, SphereSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        SphereCount = 100;
        SphereSize = 20.0f;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateSpheres();
        MoveShips ();
    }

    private void MoveShips()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < spheres [0].transform.childCount; index++) {
            Transform oneChild = spheres [0].transform.GetChild (index);
            lastPositions [index] = oneChild.transform.position;
            if (!hasRotated [index])
            {
                oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            }
            else
            {
                oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            }
        }

        if (updateOn == true) {
            for(int index =0;index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
            {
                Transform child = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);

                distanceTraveled[index] += Vector3.Distance (child.transform.position, lastPositions [index]);
                if (distanceTraveled [index] >= randomNumbers [index] && !hasRotated [index]) {
                    //child.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0f, 180f, 0f));


                    targetAngles = child.transform.eulerAngles + 180f * Vector3.up;
                    //if (!isRunning)
                    //{
                        StartCoroutine (TurnShip (child.transform, child.transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, smooth));
                    //}
                    hasRotated [index] = true;
                    child.transform.position += Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator TurnShip(Transform ship, Vector3 startAngle, Vector3 endAngle, float smooth)
    {
        isRunning = true;
        float lerpSpeed = 0;

        while(lerpSpeed < 1)
        {
            ship.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, lerpSpeed);
            lerpSpeed += 1 * smooth;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }

    private void UpdateSpheres()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && SphereCount == _sphereCount && Mathf.Approximately(SphereSize, _sphereSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sphere");
        foreach (var t in spheres)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < SphereCount; i++)
        {
            var o = Instantiate(SpaceShip);
            o.tag = "Sphere";
            o.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(SphereSize, SphereSize, SphereSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

        _extents = Extents;
        _sphereCount = SphereCount;
        _sphereSize = SphereSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are saying makes me think the local forward is simply wrong (your ship model is turned). or your forward gets changed because of parenting (wich can be tricky)

also

dont use Vector3.forward, if you want to travel on it OWN forward.

```
oneChild.transform.position += oneChild.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
```

is correct.

x

```
ship.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, lerpSpeed);
```

should be a Slerp
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html

The difference between this and linear interpolation (aka, "lerp") is that the vectors are treated as directions rather than points in space.

or lerp angle: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.LerpAngle.html

x

```
targetAngles = child.transform.eulerAngles + 180f * Vector3.up;
```

i find this last line a bit abstract, not knowing what angle you are turning on, and ,again, using vector3.up instead of child.transform.up 
but i guess this line is to flip your ship upside down, or perhaps making it move up&down

hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using the line oneChild.transform.position += oneChild.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed; and i changed the others lines but it's not helping. Still the ship/s moving up and not forward. If i will use this line instead: oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed; then the ship/s will move forward but that's not on the local.

Comment: Are you sure the local forward is pointing forward and not up? (You can Inspect it by selecting a ship, and setting the top left pivot value to local)  and did you change the lerp in your turnship function?